# ColorWell for Colored "Category"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarraycontroller, nscoder, nscolor

I have an `NSTextField`, an `NSTableView` with a column "category", an `NSColorWell`, and a custom array controller.

The `NSTextField` and the column "category" from the `NSTextField` are bound to the array controller so that everything I write in the text field shows up in this column.

The problem I have is the following:

I want the the string in the "category" column to get the color of the `NSColorWell` when the user chooses a color. All that works fine, but when I open the app a second time and I create a second entry, then the color of the string in the "category" column goes back to the first color it had before the user chose a color.

The way I'm trying this at the moment:

AppDelegate.h :

```
IBOutlet NSArrayController *doToItemsArrayController;
NSColorWell *colorWell;
- (IBAction)addNewToDoItem:(id)sender;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSColorWell *colorWell;
```

AppDelegate.m :

```
@synthesize colorWell;
- (IBAction)addNewToDoItem:(id)sender
{
    ToDoItem *newToDo = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    [newToDo setCategory:@"Beispiel-Kategorie"];
    [newToDo setColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
    [doToItemsArrayController addObject:newToDo];
}

- (IBAction)colorWellColorChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSColor *currentColor = [colorWell color];
    NSArray *selectedItems = [doToItemsArrayController selectedObjects];

    // Allen Items die Farbe geben
    // Es können ja auch mehrere ausgewählt sein.
    for (int i = 0; i < [selectedItems count] ; i++)
    {
        [[selectedItems objectAtIndex:i] setColor:currentColor];
    }
}
```

ToDoItem.h :

```
NSString *category;
NSColor *color;
@property (retain) NSString *category;
@property (retain) NSColor *color;
```

ToDoItem.m :

```
@synthesize category;
@synthesize color;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        color = [NSColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if(![super init])
        return nil;

    [self setCategory:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"category"]];
    [self setColor:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"color"]];

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:[self category] forKey:@"category"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[self color] forKey:@"color"];

}
```

I hope my code will help you to understand my problem and to get this working.

I look forward to hearing from you. Thanks.

Comment: Does nobody has an idea ? or should i explain it again a bit more specific ?!